# phpmyadmin export is doing double encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, phpmyadmin

-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.5

-- Version de PHP: 5.3.17

-- Base de donnÃ©es: `xxxx_data`

The problem is not in the data stored in the rows (even it has the same problem), it's even phpMyAdmin own labels are getting double encoded to utf-8 as you can see : "Base de donnÃ©es"
it's frensh for Database.

I'm gessing : php 5.4 version has some encoding changes somewhere (defaults to utf-8 insead of iso) and phpMyAdmin is still doing uft8_encode() in some places ...

I'm on shared hosting so can't touch phpMyAdmin code (or update).

Am I wrong ? did anyone face the same problem ?

Comment: Are you sure you are viewing the file as  UTF-8?

Comment: Sorry you were right :/ didn't expect that, when I export in plain text the problem disapeared. Didn't face this problem with other DB ... strange behavior for the gz format or my winrar ...

Comment: Perhaps the editor you are using to look at the file doesn't support UTF-8 and shows the real bytes. If you open it in a program like Notepad++, and make sure it is interpreted as UTF-8 and everything looks okay, you're fine

Comment: Perhaps http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data will help. How are you inserting the data? phpMyAdmin shouldn't be double-encoding, it's more likely your application isn't properly dealing with the data.